# Line break with graphviz, HTML

Tags: graphviz, line-breaks

I've created a [graphviz table node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062673/graphviz-node-internal-orientation/16063307#16063307):

```
<TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="3" BGCOLOR="lightgrey">LineOne LineTwo</TD>
</TR>
```

I'd like to have `Line1`, `Line2` in separate lines. I've tried `<br>`, `\n` and `&nbsp;`, without luck - some just appear as is in the rendered image, and some cause errors.

Answer (score 25):

It's a self-closing tag nitpick:

```
<TD COLSPAN="3" BGCOLOR="lightgrey">LineOne<br/>LineTwo</TD>
                                              ^
```

Comment: It's a question and an answer.